# jquery lightbox issues

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am dabbling for the first time in jquery, and we need to do a simple photo effect.

Problem is, I do everything the tutorials say to do, but no lightbox effect.

Here is the head of my html doc (without the head tags):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/assignment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.4.css" media="screen" />
   <script type="text/javascript">  
      $(function() {
        $("a.lightbox").lightBox();
    }) ;
      </script>
```

Here are my links:

```
  <aside id="comment">
    <h2>The Apes!</h2>
    <span>Lead Singer</span><span>Drums</span>
    <span>Guitar</span><span>Bass</span>
        <a href="images/Bill.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src = "images/Bill.jpg" rel="lightbox" alt="Lead Singer" title="Band member 1" /></a>
        <a href="images/Ryan.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src = "images/Ryan.jpg" rel="lightbox" alt="Guitar" title="Band member 2" /></a>
        <a href="images/Kerry.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src = "images/Kerry.jpg" rel="lightbox" alt="Drums" title="Band member 3" /></a>
        <a href="images/Bob.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src = "images/Bob.jpg" rel="lightbox" alt="Bass" title="Band member 4" /></a>
        </aside>
```

What am I missing? As I understand, I give an href of a picture to link to (the Bill image - fullsize), and a link, which is the same photo which is downsized in my css.

Aaarrgh.

Comment: If you run Firebug in Firefox or Inspector in a WebKit browser, do you see any errors in the Console window at all? I'd expect one of the files might not be loaded.

Comment: Sorry to sound like a total doofus, but how do I do that, exactly?

Comment: If you're in Safari or Chrome, if you right click on the page and go to 'Inspect Element' and click on the 'Console' tab - Refresh the page you're having problems with and see if there's any red messages in the console.

Comment: First thing download firebug for the Firefox browser: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ this will let you validate the javascript easier using the console when you open the firebug and if it shows any errors then you can start from there by analysing what is going on. Or use the Firefox Error Console that is already built in to Firefox (keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J)

Comment: Thanks.  What I am seeing is '$ is not defined  - $(document.ready(function() {   which is in my 'assignment.js' file

and 

$ is not defined - $(function(){  which is in jpuery.lightbox-.5min.js

Comment: Make sure your jquery.js and lightbox.js javascript files are where you say it is, spelled correctly, etc.

Comment: I had one of my paths screwed up, and now I am getting '('a.lightbox').lightbox() is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not downsizing the thumbnail version in CSS somewhere, your img src and hrefs point to the same images. The lightbox doesn't increase the size of an image, it just displays it. If you like using the same image names (I do), put the smaller images in a different folder than the larger ones.

Example:

```
`<a href="images/large/Bill.jpg" class="lightbox"><img src = "images/thumbs/Bill.jpg" rel="lightbox" alt="Lead Singer" title="Band member 1" /></a>`
```